# Perl Regular Expression matching digits

Tags: regex, perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter string\n";
my $str = <STDIN>;
chomp($str);

if($str =~ /[^\d*]/)
{
print "\n";
print "*********MATCHED**********\n";
}
else
{
print "\n";
print "#######WRONG############\n";
}
```

when i enter the string as  '2323adsdf'. It says matched. As for as my knowledge, it should not match as there are numbers in the string.
Can anyone please explain me, why this match occurs??

Comment: `/[^\d*]/` matches any char in the string, which is NOT digit and not literal asterisk `*`

Answer (score 2):

You need to write it that way:

[`/^[^\d]*$/`](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5E%5B%5E%5Cd%5D*%24%2F)

**Explanation:**
Your regexp [`/[^\d*]/`](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5B%5E%5Cd*%5D%2F) match part of line that does not contain digit or is `*`, so it will works as long as you have NaN characters in your line.
To mach whole line you must explicitly say that from beginning to end it is made of NaN chars

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
if($str =~ /\D/) {
    print "\nNOT a Number\n";
}
else {
    print "\nThis is a number\n";
}
```

Where `\D` matches any character that is not digit.